# Powershell Forms - changing Listbox text colors

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm trying to code a listbox-based logging/progress window in Forms and want to change the colour of the text based on the text I'm sending to it (e.g. normal, red for warning, grey for info)

I'm really new to Forms, let alone custom work like this, but I've got this far (the background colour coding isn't really necessary but I left it in):

```
$ProgressBox_DrawItem = {
    param(
        [System.Object] $sender, 
        [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs] $e
    )
    $itemIndex = $e.Index
    # $lbItem= $Sender.Items[$e.Index]
    $BgColour=[System.Drawing.Color]::White
    $TextColour = [System.Drawing.Color]::DarkGray
    If ($itemIndex -eq ($ProgressBox.Items.Count - 1)) {
        Try {
            $BgColourBrush = new-object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($BgColour)
            $e.Graphics.FillRectangle($BgColourBrush, $e.Bounds)
            $itemText = $ProgressBox.Items[$itemIndex].ToString()
            $TextColourBrush = New-Object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($TextColour)
            $e.Graphics.DrawString($itemText, $e.Font, $TextColourBrush, (new-object System.Drawing.PointF($e.Bounds.X, $e.Bounds.Y)))
        }
        Finally {
            $BgColourBrush.Dispose()
            $TextColourBrush.Dispose()
        }
    }
    Else {
    } 
}
# Add new entry
$ProgressBox.Items.Add($InputText)
# Color new item
$ProgressBox.Add_DrawItem($ProgressBox_DrawItem)
# Relocate to bottom of listbox
$ProgressBox.TopIndex = $ProgressBox.Items.Count - 1
# Refresh listbox
$ProgressBox.Update()
```

The above works, but leaves the listbox empty except for the final item, which is in the correct colours, so I assume that part of it is working fine.

I suspect I'm misunderstanding how this drawitem works - does it redraw the entire list? The behavious I was hoping for was using ".Items.Add" to add a value in default text colour and then using this to add a new entry in a different colour (leaving the rest "as-is").

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: DrawItem is called for every Listbox item. So you should handle all of them.

Comment: I suspected as much - probably too complex for this project, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's alot of article explaining how to do this in C but none I could find in PS, so in case anyone else comes across this - here's how I resolved the issue:

```
$ProgressBox.DrawMode = 'OwnerDrawFixed'
$ProgressBox_DrawItem = {
    param(
    [System.Object] $sender, 
    [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs] $e
    )
    If ($Sender.Items.Count -eq 0) {return}
    $lbItem=$Sender.Items[$e.Index]
    If ($lbItem.contains('Info')) {
        $TextColour = [System.Drawing.Color]::DarkGray
    }
    ElseIf ($lbItem.contains('(!)')) {
        $TextColour = [System.Drawing.Color]::Red
    }
    Else {
        $TextColour = [System.Drawing.Color]::Black
    }
    Try {
        $TextColourBrush = New-Object System.Drawing.SolidBrush($TextColour)
        $ItemText = $lbitem.ToString()
        $e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = 'SingleBitPerPixelGridFit'
        $e.Graphics.DrawString($itemText, $e.Font, $TextColourBrush, (new-object System.Drawing.PointF($e.Bounds.X, $e.Bounds.Y)))
    }
    Finally {
        $TextColourBrush.Dispose()
    }
}
$ProgressBox.BeginUpdate()
$ProgressBox.Items.Add($InputText)
$ProgressBox.Add_DrawItem($ProgressBox_DrawItem)
$ProgressBox.TopIndex = $ProgressBox.Items.Count - 1
$ProgressBox.EndUpdate()
```

It is however much slower than just the native method and as mentioned above I'm very new to using Forms, so if anyone can improve it feel free!